# Position of Particle; When is it parallel to x-axis.

Tags: calculus

I am going over a test question that was marked incorrect, but I am unsure as to why.

The position of a particle (in mm) is given by $x=t^3-27t$ and $y=t^2-4t$ where time t is measured in seconds. At what time is the particle moving parallel to the x-axis.

He has the answer marked as **2 seconds** however. When I calculated the t-values and graphed it at

2 seconds: $y =-3$

3 seconds: $y=-4$

4 seconds: $y=-3$

I could understand it is parallel to the x-axis at the time interval t = [2,4]. However this was a multiple choice question where the definite answer was marked as 2.

Would anyone mind explaining how you come about the soultion to this question?

Comment: Apparently the intention here is "when is the derivative of $\;y\;$ equal to zero" , so that the tangent to the particle's trajectory is parallel to the abascissa axis.

Comment: @DonAntonio Which yes that is what it seems like on the surface, but when we did these problems in class we never did anything like that. Also if that is the case what is the point of x?

Comment: I don't know, @Bob, but who cares? Since a negative value is obtained for $\;t=2\;$ on $\;x\;$ I suppose that means the particle's to the left of the origin...or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the position function $r(t)=(t^3-27t,t^2-4t)$.The instant the velocity of $r(t)$, that is, $v(t)=r'(t)=(3t^2-27,2t-4)$, has no y-component, it is moving parallel to the x-axis. That is, when $2t-4=0$ or $t=2$.